# Unknown syntax used to describe Source for Akka-stream: "#Repr"

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

Quite new to Akka streams and I came across this piece of code the other day while at work. I'm not exactly sure what's going on here, and the developer who initially wrote this is long gone.

Can anyone here please shed some light on what the '#Repr[A]' snippet of code is actually doing.

Tried looking this up online but found nothing.

```
package models

import akka.stream.scaladsl.Source
import akka.util.ByteString
import models.CsvModels._

object CsvFileModels {
  type CsvSource = Source[ByteString,Any]#Repr[ByteString]#Repr[List[ByteString]]#Repr[Map[String, String]]
}
```

Compiles fine, just trying to figure out exactly what is going on here.

Comment: Any chance you can share the usage of CsvSource? I know that `#` refers to a class or type within a class without creating an instance of that class, but this looks like some shape from ByteString to Map[String, String]. Very curious!

Comment: It's use case is context sensitive, so it won't make sense unless I paste a large majority of the code. However, your comment pointed me in the right direction, thanks a ton!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called *type projection*. It is somewhat equivalent to `.` in Java.

I.e.

```
Foo#Bar
```

in Scala, is somewhat equivalent to

```
Foo.Bar
```

in Java.